# how to return custom error on graphql with typeorm and apollo

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm

Hello i'm trying to return an error custom
an example the user creates and the email is exists:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The email exists",
      "statusCode": "400"
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

i have this now:

**my APP.TS**:

```
export async function startServer() {
  const app = express();
  const schema = await createSchema();
  useContainer(Container);
  const connection = await createConnection();
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: ({ req, res }: any) => ({ req, res }),
  });
  server.applyMiddleware({ app });
  return app;
}
```

**Resovler.TS**:

```
@Resolver()
export class CreateUserResolver {
  //dependency inject
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}

  //create User Mutaton
  @Mutation(() => User)
  async register(
    @Arg('data')
    data: RegisterInput,
  ): Promise<Partial<User> | Object> {
    const user = this.userService.findOrCreate(data);
    return user;
  }
}
```

**Input:**

```
@InputType()
export class RegisterInput {
  @Field()
  @IsEmail({}, { message: 'Invalid email' })
  email: string;

  @Field()
  @Length(1, 255)
  name: string;

  @Field()
  password: string;
}
```

**Service:**

```
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private userRep: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  async findOrCreate(data: Partial<User>): Promise<Partial<User> | Object> {
    let user = await this.userRep.findOne({ where: { email: data.email } });
    if (user) throw new Error('user already exists');
    data.password = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, 12);
    user = await this.userRep.save({
      ...data,
    });
    return user;
  }
```

At the moment the only solution I found was to use:

> if (user) throw new Error ('user already exists');

But I'm not able to imagine how I could use the status code or return only the error message and not all this message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the right way. You should stick to the errors generated by Apollo because its a graphql standard. Of course you don't want to show the stacktraces to the enduser. To disable stacktraces for production, pass `debug: false` to the Apollo Server constructor.

Source: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/